# Check with PropTypes if props is a valid JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

How to check if a  **placeholderProp** `props` of type *string* is valid JSON using `prop-types` package?

in the parent Component:

```
<Component placeholderProp={'{"a":1}} />
```

Component.js

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

const Component = ()=>{ ... }

Component.propTypes= {
  placeholderProp: PropTypes.???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right after checking github page of `prop-types`, I realized the solution was through using a 
 *function*:

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

const Component = ()=>{ ... }

Component.propTypes= {
  placeholderProp: function(props, propName, componentName) {
    try {
      JSON.parse(props[propName]);
    } catch (e) {
      return new Error('Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.');
    }
  }
}
```